# latex compact table of contents?

Tags: latex

I would like to use the \tableofcontents command but without the table of contents starting on a new page or creating a new page at the end and also have everything be single spaced. How can I do this? Using tocloft I assume, but what options?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the `minitoc` package.

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured out everything except for one question. How do I get \tableofcontents to not start a new page?

Comment: i believe, though i can not check right now, that the new page with the toc depends on what document class you're using. the article class doesn't start the toc on a new page, while report & book do. I'd look into article.cls and see how that is achieved. i also believe that with the book & report classes, that the toc header is set with the \chapter{}, so it will start on a new page. just redefine that command.